# Sequence ALTER RESTART does not affect on the current value of a sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why the next ALTER does not define currval of the sequence comments_comment_id_seq?

```
db=# alter sequence comments_comment_id_seq restart with 65545;
ALTER SEQUENCE
db=# SELECT currval('comments_comment_id_seq');
ERROR:  currval of sequence "comments_comment_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session
db=#
```

**Additional detail**

The table which owns the sequence is a child of another table:

```
   Column   |            Type             |                             Modifiers              
------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 comment_id | bigint                      | not null default nextval('comments_base_comment_id_seq'::regclass)
 auser_id   | bigint                      | not null
 dt         | timestamp without time zone | not null
 text       | text                        | not null
 is_deleted | smallint                    | default 0
 parent     | bigint                      | default 0
 post_id    | bigint                      | not null
Indexes:
    "comments_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (comment_id)
Inherits: comments_base
```

Comment: As the [`ALTER SEQUENCE ...  RESTART WITH ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html) is "is equivalent to calling the setval function with is_called = false: the specified value will be returned by the next call of nextval." So you still need to call `nextval` first to have a working `currval`.

Comment: @MilenA.Radev Yes, it works after the nextval(). It fixies the error for the 'current session'. But when I logged out and login again to psql then the error occurs again. Could you advice how to fix that please?

Comment: Calling `currval` is only valid in a session in which there was already a call to `nextval` (or `setval` with `is_called=true`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you restart the sequence you set it into a state like it was just created. And in this case you don't have a currval before you first selected a nextval.